# iOS In-App Purchases and Selling in-app Currency

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

In App where you sell an "in App Currency"; is it okay to also allow ways to get the currency without paying for it? Like have currency in the App for purchasing add-ons, but allow the user to purchase the currency or unlock it by doing various other things in the App.

I've already read that selling in-app currencies is against Apple's policy, but there seems to be a lot of people doing it.

I've been trying to find the answer to this for a while now and haven't come up with anything.

Comment: I've seen this a lot : coins with which you can buy stuff, and IAP lets you buy coins faster than you earn them in-game. I'd say from experience that it's okay. It may help though to tell us where you read that "selling in-app currencies is against Apple's policy".

Comment: Did you search for 'currency' in that app store review guidelines document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, it is a much used practice to have an "in-app currency". We may call them "coins" for the example. It is perfectly allowed to have a game in which you can earn those "coins", and add in-app purchases so the player can buy them (and therefore get some faster).

Here is an extract of Apple's document "[In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)" :

> You may sell credits or virtual currency provided they are used within
>   the app and do not have a time limit imposed upon them.

So, I think you're good to go !